# Botón dentro de un RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Tengo un `RecyclerView` que tiene un botón en los items *(Obviamente es el mismo botón para todos los items con la misma función ya que este estilo es inflado de un layout)*, lo que intento es que al hacer click en el botón se elimine este item. Esto lo hice desde el adaptador. ASÍ

```
public class Adaptador extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador.ViewHolder> 
implements View.OnClickListener{
ArrayList<Personas> personas;
View.OnClickListener listener;

public Adaptador(ArrayList<Personas> personas) {
    this.personas = personas;
}

@Override
public Adaptador.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

 View view =   LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.formato_lista,null,false);

    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Adaptador.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.Nombre.setText(personas.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.Edad.setText(personas.get(position).getEdad());
    holder.Genero.setText(personas.get(position).getSexo());
    holder.Pais.setText(personas.get(position).getPais());

    holder.eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            personas.remove(position);
            Adaptador.this.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return personas.size();
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener)
{
 this.listener = listener;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (listener!=null)
    {
        listener.onClick(view);
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    TextView Nombre;
    TextView Edad;
    TextView Pais;
    TextView Genero;
    Button eliminar;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Nombre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Nombre);
        Edad = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Edad);
        Pais = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Pais);
        Genero = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Genero);
        eliminar = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.eliminar);

        eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                personas.remove(position);
                Adaptador.this.notifyItemRemoved(position);

            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

En `OnBindViewHolder` use el `OnClickListener` para eliminar y notificar. Funciona a medias ya que si los elimino de abajo hacia arriba funciona bien, si empiezo a  de arriba hacia abajo se cierra la aplicación e igual que si empiezo en desorden.

Y si lo hago desde `ViewHolder` no  puedo capturar la posición.

Comment: En vez de crear una nueva instancia de adaptador (Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(personas); ) porque no intentas hacer Adaptador.this.NotifyItemRemoved(position); de igual manera, te recomiendo implementar OnClick y hacer el SetOnClickListener en la clase del ViewHolder y no en el OnBindViewHolder. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya hice la modificación de codigo pero sigo con el error. Y el ViewHolder lo que te entiendo es hacer esto: eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {



                    personas.remove(position);
                    Adaptador.this.notifyItemRemoved(position);

                }
            });                                                                                               o no te refieres a eso? 

Pasa que en esta clase no puedo usar la variable position

Comment: getAdapterPosition(); te permite obtener la posicion del item que representa el ViewHolder. En caso que no exista en la subclase, intenta con El nombre de tu holder.this, ej: ViewHolder.this.getAdapterPosition();

Answer (score 0):

Estas creando una nueva instancia del Adaptador cuando deberias de utilizar la instancia propia donde Adaptador.

Cambia:

```
Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(personas);

personas.remove(position);
adaptador.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Por:

```
personas.remove(position);
Adaptador.this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Y asi lo eliminaras del `Adaptador` actual que se esta visualizando, no una nueva instancia.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya actualice el codigo pero sigo con el problema

Answer (score 0):

Estimado tiene que se en el OnBindViewHolder pero ademas tu recyclerview tiene que tener esta magica linea de codigo

```
Recyclcer recyclerview;
Lista listapersonalizda;
recyclerview.setItemViewCacheSize(listapersonalizda.size());
```

Porque es esto  bueno tu recycler view tiene digamos una vida y muestra solo las posiciones que tenga en cache y varian dependiendo el scroll, y pueden ser otras si no quieres usar eso puedes usar trucos sucios (dirty secrets) como por ejemplo crear un textview con visibilidad GONE donde almacenes la posicion real, porque cuando obtienes la posición no estas obteniendo la posición real sino la posición de la lista, o puedes usar holder.getAdapterPosition(); que conservas la posicion de tu LISTA y no consultas la de tu recycler con la variable position

La razón por la que no te funciona de abajo hacia arriba es la misma ya que al si eliminas por ejemplo la posición 3 de tu lista  pero tu scrool aun tendra la posicion 3 y si intentas eliminar de nuevo después de hacer scrol veras un error ya que no existe y el recycler la ordeno nuevamente,  puedes comprobar lo que te estoy diciendo usando try catch al elimiar el item y ver el log, debe salir que apuntas a un algo que no existe
Aqui una imagen descriptiva

Image
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aquí el articulo donde explican todo esto

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://android.jlelse.eu/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-404ba3453714)